# Laravel 5.6 shows me 'index of /' page

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I was following this link to install Laravel 5.6:
https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/how-install-laravel-5-5-php-7-apache-centos-7/

I don't change DocumentRoot "/var/www/html".

When I visit the URL, it shows me an index page of /

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You've got some missing files, a missing `public` directory, and your `DocumentRoot` should be pointed *at* that missing `public` directory.

Comment: It has public directory in my server.

Comment: Why isn't it showing up in that index, then?